# Sam's Cruise ship

Tags: pattern

Sam is going on a cruise around the world and with him on his cruise ship he takes the following collection of flora and fauna:

```
14  ibises  
13  hives  
12  fish  
11  asses  
10  seeds  
9   hens  
8   bees  
7   daisies  
6   flies  
5   leeches  
4   cheetahs  
3   deer  
2   pigs  
1   wolf  
1/2 kangaroo  
1/3 coyote  
1/4 root
```

He later decides he also wants to bring eels, lilies and puppies. Which of the items/animals on his current list can he leave behind in exchange for these?

Of which of the following items could he bring 11/12th to make the total an integer number (107)?

```
 a) mushroom
 b) broccoli   
 c) cauliflower   
 d) chestnut
```

**Hint:**

> This story is about a famous Sam.

Comment: a half of a kangaroo and a third of a coyote? Sam is a sick dude.

Comment: Uuuuugh $107$ is my least favorite number ever.  And good luck getting on any cruise ship with all of that in tow.  I dislike this Sam fellow.

Comment: Can I nominate a kangaroo to be sliced in half?

Comment: @Rubio: As long as you don't nominate Skippy the Bush Kangaroo...

Comment: I'm pretty sure Rubio had someone else in mind.

Comment: Something about paired letters..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number associated with each word is

> the ratio of the number of dits to the number of dahs when it's transcribed in Morse code. (The hint was a biiiiig giveaway!)

So

> eels (. . .-.. ...) score 8 and could replace bees;
>  lilies (.-.. .. .-.. .. . ...) score 14/2=7 and could replace daisies;
>  puppies (.--. ..- .--. .--. .. . ...) score 14/7=2 and could replace pigs.

And

> mushroom (-- ..- ... .... .-. --- --- --) scores 11/12 and is the answer to the second question. Broccoli (-... .-. --- -.-. -.-. --- .-.. ..) scores 14/13; cauliflower (-.-. .- ..- .-.. .. ..-. .-.. --- .-- . .-.) scores 20/13; and chestnut (-.-. .... . ... - -. ..- -) scores 14/6.

Comment: Nice, that's it!

Comment: That hint was ... informative :-).

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I might have thought about that one a little longer :P

Comment: Though it was a real why-the-hell-didn't-I-think-of-that one, so I'm not sure what you could have done to make the hint informative but not a giveaway...